# What does mean code EXEC_I386_GPFLT when program crashes with EXC_BAD_ADDRESS

Tags: swift, macos, exc-bad-access

I have my OSX program crashing with EXC_BAD_ADDRESS with code EXEC_I386_GPFLT.

I do not have any usual message like no selector found...

The program was working before, I've just changed the calling system. It was a self made hotkey manager, I now use MASShorcut.

I suspect a threading issue and I think I'll fix the problem with dispatch_xx block.

So the actual question is: what EXEC_I386_GPFLT means ?

```
func saveFile() {
     // crashes on following line
    let savePanel = NSSavePanel(contentRect: NSRect(), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, `defer`: true)
    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    ...
```

[image: The stack trace when it crashes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXEC_I386_GPFLT` is a *general protection fault*.

It usually means your app tried to dereference an address that wasn't just to some unreadable part of memory, but is wildly preposterous and references something that cannot be memory at all (on a 64 bit system, there isn't really 64 bits of addressable space as some of the bits are used as metadata in certain contexts, for example.)

Given that the crash and the call are on the main thread, it doesn't look like a threading issue (at least, not with the evidence given).

Typically, you create a save panel with `NSSavePanel()`.  Given that it is crashing in alloc/init, I'd suggest moving to the standard way of creating one.

Comment: Replacing the construction by just `let savePanel = NSSavePanel()` made it work. Weird crash IMHO.

Comment: @Xvolks Very weird crash.  I'd suggest filing a bug report.